# What architecture to follow when I need to make user login in Android app?

Tags: architecture, unit-testing, android, android-development, annotations

I am writing an android app. Some of its functionalities require the user to be authenticated. I am planning to create an annotation like this:

```
@RequiresAuth
fun commentOnTask(){
  ....
}
```

This annotation would check user status. If authenticated the function would be called; if not, it would navigate to login screen. After successful auth function will be called or it must navigate to previous screen.

Is it proper way, or there are better alternatives? Also I am thinking how would I test this after.

Answer (score 1):

This is simple and could work. Another alternative:

Put this responsibility of authentication / authorization on an [API gateway](https://nordicapis.com/what-is-an-api-gateway/) - This way you can reuse this kind of authentication / authorization logic across different applications.

You also free your application to be tested in isolation from the authentication / authorization logic, which is generally well tested if you are using gateway tools like AWS API gateway with OAuth providers like Auth0, Okta, etc.

Comment: I think the OP was referring to mobile UI implementation, but I agree that it's not clear from the question body. I just figured out looking at tags